# Plugin edit made Wordpress.org admin panel broken

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I went and edited a plugin called Huge IT portfolio and added an echo "1"; exit(); in it and now i can't access the admin panel (yet i can access the site) it just gives me the echo 1.

What can I do to revert the changes to it? I can't even paste the code anymore since i can't access it

Comment: Backspace will do it, if you still have the session

Comment: Use FTP to rename the plugin folder.

Comment: also you can use ftp to download the file, edit it (remove the echo 1;exit(); and re-upload it(it's better for production if you have lots of plugins (not recommended to edit plugins on production website - but this is another story )).

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the admin panel anymore you have a few options, they all involve accessing the website via FTP.

1. Rename the plugins folder (ex plugins_old), logging in now will cause all plugins to disable.
2. Rename the directory of your specific plugin, logging in now will cause this plugin to disable.
3. Download the file you edited in the WordPress dashboard, undo your edits and upload it again.